# "Jobs near you" panel customization

Tags: feature-request

Stackoverflow is displaying a side panel named "Jobs near you".

As I am currently looking for a new job, but I don't want to find it "near me", I think it would be useful if it were possible to customize the desired location for such a service.

On a side note, it seems the service is not currently working as whenever I click on the title "Jobs near you" at the top of the panel or on the link "More jobs near..." at the bottom of the panel I am redirected to a white page showing "Not Found".

Comment: This would be really useful - everyday I see Jobs near blah but I'm never going to click on any of them because my location is not where I'm looking

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ directly to use all sorts of different criteria for searching for jobs.

Comment: It seems to me like you can set your current location but not the location where you wish to find a job at. Anyway I don't think it's even that because the "Jobs near you" panel shows the jobs nearby the place I am browsing, not the one I have set in the location field of my profile.