# Missing out on relevant Job Recommendations because of "Jobs Near Me"

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

> There have been multiple older threads around the issue but none have
> a solution - eg [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209037/269248),
> [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268419/careers-should-allow-me-to-specify-the-area-from-which-i-want-to-see-job-offers), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283742/jobs-near-you-panel-customization)

I am currently exploring opportunities and have specified a few locations in my Job Preferences. Despite it, I am seeing Job recommendations that are local to my current residence only. There is no way to disable these and this is causing me to not see some of the recommendations which I would want to see.

How do I

- Disable "Jobs Near Me"?

OR

- See recommendations for the locations specified?